# porting Linux socket programming (Python) to Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, sockets, firewall

I have a code which consists of something similar to this, which works in Linux. Now i want to port this to Windows. I know that Windows uses winsock for socket programming but is it possible to implement this python module "socket" in windows as well?

````
   ```
     import socket
    host = self.config.get_config('BASE_ADDRESS',BASE_ADDRESS_VAL)
    port = self.config.get_config('BASE_PORT',BASE_PORT_VAL)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    if sock is None:
        print('could not open socket')
        sys.exit(1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.append(sock)
    self.log.info('Listening to %s:%s' % (host, port))
    try:
        sock.bind((host, int(port)))

    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
    #sock.bind(("10.0.0.1", ""))
    while self.winParent.ongoing==True:
        try:
            r,w,e = select.select(self.sock, [], self.sock,self.timeout)
            for sock in r:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(556)
                #something = sock.recvfrom(556)
                #print(something[0].decode())
                self.handle(sock, addr, data)
        except (Exception, e):
            import traceback
            self.log.critical('%s\n%s' % (str(e), traceback.format_exc()))
            time.sleep(1)

    for sock in self.sock:
        sock.close()
    self.sock = []
````

```
My code gets stuck at "r,w,e = select.select(self.sock, [], self.sock,self.timeout)".


On investigating with Wireshark, I can see the following:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNxKH.png

I have the following points of doubt :
(1) Could this be a firewall issue?  I have added python.exe to allow through Firewall in Windows Defender. Am I missing something basic?
(2) Should I have the winsock.dll installed separately?
```

Comment: `socket` library working both on Windows and Linux, why you want to port it?

Comment: @rozumir I am porting a codebase that is now working in Linux PC to run in Windows PC. And This socket prog is a part of it. I am not able to establish socket communication  between my PC and my HW connected via PoE. I was wondering if this python module is adaptable to Windows.

Comment: The socket module works fine on Windows. Did you try to send a datagram from the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

The `socket` module works just fine on Windows and that's not the source of the problem here. As you've helpfully pointed out, it's `select` where your code gets stuck (the posix `select()` is the traditional Unix way of servicing sockets). It's supposed to get stuck, as it's sitting and waiting for incoming packets :) You *are* sending some packets to it, right?

Since you're expecting incoming UDP packets the Windows Firewall might need additional convincing to allow those. Double-check with a quick Google search.

Comment: If `(self.sock, [], self.sock)` is a tuple of 3 empty iterable, then `self.sock, self.sock, self.sock)` will be too...

Comment: The wording is a bit vague, but there's no mention of a tuple. Those are function arguments, and in my interpretation every one must be supplied with a value you can interate over (if only once). Come to think of it, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Probably Windows Firewall is just blocking the incoming UDP packets.

Comment: No it is explicit: any of the iterable may be empty provided not all three are. I have successfully use empty iterables for `wlist` and `xlist` on Windows, provided `rlist` contains at least one socket. And in a more complex use case, I could use empty lists for `rlist` and `xlist` when `wlist` was not empty.

Comment: Yeah, that would make more sense. I'll update my answer.